# Deleting a selected NSTableView row from Core Data?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nstableview

How would I delete selected NSTableView row and it's corresponding Core Data entry?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your `NSTableView` is bound to an `NSArrayController` (which is the most common pattern when dealing with Core Data), you can just use `NSArrayController`'s [`remove:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSArrayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArrayController/remove:) method:

```
[theArrayController remove:self];
```

This will delete all objects which are selected in the array controller.

---

Otherwise, if you're *not* bound to an `NSArrayController`, you'll need to deal with the selected object directly. Without knowing how you're populating your tableView, I can't show all of the necessary code, but presumably you can find which `NSManagedObject` is selected. Once you have that object, it's a cinch to delete it:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = the managed object context for your objects;
NSManagedObject *selectedObject = the currently-selected object;
[moc deleteObject:selectedObject];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the row using the method `tableView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:row:` of `NSTableViewDataSource`, and then forcing the table to be updated using the method `reloadData` of `NSTableView`.

Comment: Will that remove the Core Data entry (BTW I'm using Bindings)

Comment: Doing as I reported, you just remove the object from the table (the one that is passed as `setObjectValue:` in `tableView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:row:`. You need to then delete the object.

Comment: I explain myself better. In Objective-C, each created object has a variable that keeps count of the number of references to that object; when that counter is zero, then the object is deallocated. When you pass an object to another object (which stores it in its properties), that counter is increased, and decreased when that object is not stored in the other object properties. If you are new to Cocoa/Objective-C, you should read http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html.

Comment: I get Memory Management (I think), but removing the row from the table view I don't understand.

Comment: Oh… Pass `nil` as value for `setObjectValue:`.

Comment: What do you call tableView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:row: on?

Comment: Please deselect the answer I gave; I misread what you wrote, and gave a not correct / partial answer.